# Flipping a Coin until 3 heads appear

Tags: c++

Write a program that simulates flipping a coin repeatedly and continues until three consecutive heads are tossed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "random.h"

using namespace std;
enum CoinSide {heads, tails}; 
CoinSide FlipCoin(int flip);

int main(){ 
    int flip;
    int heads = 0;
    int total_flips = 0;
    while( heads < 3){
        total_flips++;
        if(FlipCoin(flip) == heads){
            heads++;
        } else{
            heads = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "it took " << total_flips << "to get 3 consecutive heads. " << endl;

}   

CoinSide FlipCoin(int flip) {
    if (randomChance(0.50)) {
        return "heads";
    } else {
        return "tails";
    }
}
```

Now I am getting an unknown error, when I run this code, anyone know why it wont run>?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by comparing a boolean (true/false) with `"heads"` !?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FlipCoin` returns a boolean (integral) value, and comparison against a `const char*` is illegal. `"heads"` and `"tails"` are just that.

You can return a `std::string` to perform a comparison, but I'd suggest you have an `enum CoinSide {HEADS, TAILS};` and return that instead.

```
CoinSide FlipCoin(int flip) {
    if (randomChance(0.50)) {
        return HEADS;
    }
    return TAILS;
}
```

and

```
if (FlipCoin(flip) == HEADS)
```

Comment: I tried to implement the following changes but it is still not running

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 what does debugging tell you?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 You didn't implement those changes. Your `FlipCoin` function has a `Coinside` return type (which is an enum) but you still return `"heads"` or `"tails"` which are c-strings. It should be noted that the code in the question was updated based on the answer rendering it partially invalid (maybe a rollback is in order?)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I do not know how to De-Bug I am using Netbeans IDE

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 debugging is vital. You should first learn that, above all else.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above answer:

Please do yourself and anybody who might have to look over your code a favor by never ever using the same name for different things and try to use those different things in the same context. In this case I'm talking about

```
enum CoinSide {heads, tails}; // <- This
CoinSide FlipCoin(int flip);

int main(){ 
    int flip;
    int heads = 0;            // <- in combination with this! Because:
    int total_flips = 0;
    while( heads < 3){
        total_flips++;
        if(FlipCoin(flip) == heads){ 
            // You might think you're comparing
            // FlipCoin(int)::CoinSide vs. CoinSide::heads
            // But(!) you compare
            // FlipCoint(int)::CoinSide vs. main::heads
            // The very main::heads you're going to increase now.
            heads++;
        } else{
            heads = 0;
        }
    } // Will never terminate.
    cout << "it took " << total_flips << "to get 3 consecutive heads. " << endl;

}
```

If you use constant values which mean something you should

a) make them visually stand out, e.g. using *HEADS* or *TAILS* instead of *heads* or *tails* in enums.
b) never ever give two things the same name and (try to) use them in the same context.

This will save you some serious case of head scratching in the future.